# How do I dump all the properties of a Java object and of the objects in it recursively?

Tags: java, tostring, apache-commons

I need to dump the whole structure of na object, with the values of all its properties and of the objects it is composed of.

I can't implement `toString()` in the dumped objects because most of them are auto-generated code.

I thought I would be able to use `ReflectionToStringBuilder` and `RecursiveToStringStyle`, from Apache Commons, for this, but for all my attempts all I get is the first level of the hierarchy.

This is what I tried, for example:

```
System.out.println(new ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(someObject, new RecursiveToStringStyle()));
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: The javadocs for RecursiveToStringStyle show that it's recursive with an example. Can you give me an example of what you are looking for and/or how RecursiveToStringStyle doesn't work?

Comment: @omajid, The sample shows how to use it to implement your own `toString()`. Since the class is auto-generated, I can't change its `toString()` implementation. `ToStringBuilder` works and appears to have support for dumping recursively, so I'm guessing that it is just a matter of calling it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use **reflection** to get all of the properties of the top level object, and **recursion** to repeat the process for each object that is returned as a property.

Take care not to get into an infinite loop if an object has one of its parents stored in a property.

Comment: I'm being lazy and trying not to write new code if that is already available and tested as part of a framework. :-)